# Include variable in filename perl

Tags: perl, variables, filenames

I'm trying to create a script which searches for particular errors in a logfile. The logfile is date stamped so I want to check just todays log file. This will end up as a cronjob. When I run this. I currently get the below error:

> tail: cannot open `/var/log/file.2014-09-03-Wed\n.log' for reading: No
>   such file or directory

So I get the date, but then there's a \n which is added. Script below:

```
$date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%a"`;
$string = `tail -n50 /var/log/"file.$date.log" | grep -B2 'Too many connected clients'`;

if($string =~ m/Reply: 421 Service not available. There are too many connected users, please try later/){
print "Max connections reached $date"
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why do you using perl if 50% of lines are external commands? maybe an simple bash script....

Comment: Or alternatively, rewrite in perl -  file reading and date formatting are pretty basic perl operations.

Comment: I do a lot of bash, but trying to learn perl for work purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `chomp($data)` or `$date =~s/\n//;`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `\n` from `$date`:

```
chomp($date);
```

Comment: $date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%a"`;
chomp($date);
$string = `tail -n50 '/var/log/file.$date.log' | grep -B2 'Too many connected clients'`;
if($string =~ m/Reply: 421 Service not available. There are too many connected users, please try later/){
print "Max connections reached. $date"
}

Comment: @user3573036: Sorry, I don't get you. Isn't the `chomp` fixing the problem?

Comment: @user3573036: What is the status of this question, please? And why have you posted a chunk of code as a comment?

Comment: Chomp fixed the problem. I'm very new to perl, so have never come across it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Time::Piece` module to get formatted dates and times, rather than starting a whole other process to do it. It has been a core module since version 10 of Perl 5 and so won't need installing unless your Perl is extremely old.

It looks like this

```
use Time::Piece;

my $date = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%a');
print $date, "\n";
```

**output**

```
2014-09-03-Wed
```